# Excel VBA showing specific rows

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I am creating a holidayplanner for my Department. We are about 150 People in 9 Groups. I want to create a button which filters the members of each Group.

At the Moment I use this code:

```
Sub IFK02einblenden()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ActiveSheet.Rows(8).Hidden = True
    ActiveSheet.Rows(9).Hidden = False
    ActiveSheet.Rows(10).Hidden = True
    ActiveSheet.Rows(11).Hidden = True
    ActiveSheet.Rows(12).Hidden = False
    ActiveSheet.Rows(13).Hidden = False
    ActiveSheet.Rows(14).Hidden = False
    ActiveSheet.Rows(15).Hidden = True
    ActiveSheet.Rows(16).Hidden = True
    //and so on and so on till row 158

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

With 9 modules like this the performance of the macros is very poor.

Do you have an idea to optimize this with range attributes or something else?

At click on the button "Group ONE" The members of Group ONE should be shown like "show me row 8 AND row 12-38"

Comment: Could you not use AutoFilter?

Comment: What criteria you use to hide a row?

Comment: No than everybody has to use the filter every time instead of clicking a button. there are many logics and calculations which are exported to other Excel files.

Comment: At the Moment i do it manually with the code above. I like to declare a Rangeobject for specify the "Groups" but i don't know how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use filter and any other alternative then please try something like this

```
    Sub GroupOne()
    ActiveSheet.Rows("8:8").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ActiveSheet.Rows("12:38").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End Sub
```